# Validation is not checking the value on spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, validation

I'm using `@NotBlank` and `@Size` annotations.

Partial code below:

```java
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;


public class WatchlistItem {

    @NotBlank(message="You cannot leave it empty")
    private String title;
    private String rating;
    @NotBlank(message = "cannot leave blank")
    private String priority;

    @Size(max = 50, message = "The maximum characters are 50")
    private String comment; 
    ...
}
```

Part of the controller class:

```java
    @PostMapping("/watchlistItemForm")
    public  ModelAndView submitWatchlistItemForm(@Valid WatchlistItem watchlistItem,
                                                BindingResult bindingResult ){

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            return new ModelAndView ("watchlistItemForm");
        }
        WatchlistItem updateItem = getWatchListItemById(watchlistItem.getId());
        ...
    }
```

And the pom file:

```xml
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.openclassrooms</groupId>
    <artifactId>watchlist23</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>watchlist23</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

But when I run the application, I can leave the title field blank and still works, whereas it should stop and ask me to enter the title.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Javax, I had to use Jakarta libraries. It is working now.

```
 //import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
//import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;
```